# What was this story about an antagonist being trapped in a time loop, repeating his death endlessly?

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

Ok, so what I remember is a fight on a spaceship that results in the antagonist being trapped, onboard, in a time loop that endlessly repeats the ship exploding. He dies over and over again while the protagonist gets safely away.

I don't know if it's a short story, part of a novel, a movie... I would have seen/read it in the 60's or 70's most likely. Can anyone ID this?

Comment: Was it Star Trek? This sounds like a *Star Trek: The Next Generation* episode.

Comment: @RobertF Except in that episode the explosion in the time loop was the result of an accident, not a fight on the ship

Comment: That's similar to Futurama, no?

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GroundhogDayLoop

Comment: @RobertF It does remind me of the Star Trek episode "The Alternative Factor", except in that one both the good guy and the bad guy get trapped together forever.

Comment: @JohnP <s>assume it's the *Outer Limits* episode on that list?</s> never mind, time scale's all wrong&lt;/irony>